# Committing and Rollback using Atomic Keyword

Tags: sql, sybase, isql

I am working on the sybase isql. I have a set of update statements that needs to be like either all updates are successful or hone. For that I am trying to execute using the atomic function of sybase . But it is showing error as "incorrect syntax near 'atomic', 'end'.

```
begin atomic
update abc 
set def = q
update xyz
set xyz = p
end
```

ase isql not showing atomic as a keyword . Does sybase won't support atomic keyword?

Answer (score 2):

For your solution You should use transaction as below

```
begin tran atomic
update abc 
set def = q

if @@error <> 0 
rollback tran atomic

update xyz
set xyz = p

if @@error <> 0 
rollback tran atomic

commit tran atomic
```

You can use the transaction without word `Atomic`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. But here I am asking about the atomic block of statements in the sybase. The condition was that if the above statement won't work then all the remaining update statements should rollback.

Comment: @10hero Above code do what you want. If one of the statement isn't work than all changes will rollback.